# Firebase Android, me llegan las notificaciones sin sonido

Tags: php, android, firebase, mensajes, notificaciones

Tengo una aplicación en android con firebase messaging, las notidicaciones cuando me llegan las muestro con una notificación personalizada (sonido, color, vibración, icono, ... ). Todo bien hasta ahí, cuando se tiene la aplicación abierta , pero ahora cuando se cierra la app, y mando la notificación, este se muestra con una notificación básica (sin sonido, con el icono de la app, sin vibración ). no lo muestra con mi notificación personalizada.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessageReceived extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private final String TAG = "MessageReceived";
private SharedPreferences spNotification;
private SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;
private static Set<String> listaNotificaciones;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        String tipoMensaje = remoteMessage.getData().get("tipoMensaje").toString();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String titulo = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        switch (tipoMensaje) {
            case "hora":
                mostrarNotificacion(construirNotificacionHora(titulo, body, tipoMensaje), 2);
                break;
        }
    }

}

private void mostrarNotificacion(Notification notification, int id) {
    //NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
}

private Notification construirNotificacionHora(String titulo, String body, String chanelId) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, chanelId) // ANDROID 8
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setColor(Color.parseColor("#71b32a"))
                    .setContentTitle(titulo)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
    //.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    return builder.build();
}
```

}

Agrego también que las notificaciones lo envió a mi celular es desde mi servidor php, y no desde la pagina de firebase.

```
class messengerServiceFCM {

var $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

public function __construct() {

}

public function sendMessenger($autorization, $token, $tipoMensaje, $title, $body) {

    $fields = json_encode(Array(
        // "registration_ids" => "",
        //  "condition" => "",
        //"to" => $token, // "/topics/androide",  //"/topics/androide"
        "registration_ids" => $token,
        "notification" => Array(
            "title" => $title,
            "body" => $body
        ),
        "data" => Array(
            "tipoMensaje" => $tipoMensaje
        )
    ));
    $headers = Array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization:key=' . $autorization
    );

    $ch = curl_init($this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result == FALSE) {
        return (["error" => curl_error($ch)]);
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### * Actualización:

#### a partir de API 26 Android 8, el sonido lo determina el dispositivo, pero si desea definir un sonido "personalizado" este debe definirse al canal:

```
   Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mysound);

 AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();

   mChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
```

---

#### Para agregar sonido a tu notificación, debes usar el método [**setSound()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes))  de `NotificationCompat.Builder`

ejemplo declarando el sonido default:

```
 Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

posteriormente asignalo a tu   `NotificationCompat.Builder`  :

```
 .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
```

---

en tu código sería:

```
private Notification construirNotificacionHora(String titulo, String body, String chanelId) {

  Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, chanelId) // ANDROID 8
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setColor(Color.parseColor("#71b32a"))
                    .setContentTitle(titulo)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri) //* Sonido!
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
    //.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: El problema es que no entra ni siquiera a la función.
Al parecer crea otra notificación básica, sin sonido ni vibración. y eso pasa solamente cuando el app esta cerrada, porque cuando esta abierta si muestra con el sonido.

Comment: Si no entra a la función entonces como se puede construir una notificación básica. Agrega una imagen de lo que comentas.

Comment: si borro la función que imprime la notificación y ejecuto el app, luego lo cierro. y mando la notificación desde mi servidor php, aumaticamente sale un notificación básica, con el titulo y el cuerpo.

Comment: cual es "la función que imprime la notificación" ?

Comment: "mostrarNotificacion" & "construirNotificacionHora"

Comment: =-0 construirNotificacionHora() en realidad es quien crea la notificación dices que las borrras y ves una notificación?. revisa si en tu código tienes otro método donde uses : NotificationCompat.Builder